# Lowest-power laptop

Tags: laptop, power

Looking for the lowest-power laptop possible, for use off grid powered by a very small solar array. My Yoga 2 11 draws 14 watts at idle (or what I would call idle, anyway). Five watts would be better. Four would be better still. Etc.

Should be a real laptop (not tablet) with a real keyboard (not chiclet). I watch videos on it, but other than that no heavy lifting. I have looked at the EnergyStar listings, found them difficult to use, and am unsure how to compare their numbers with my real-life experience.

Specific recommendations are welcome. So are general principles, e.g. which types of components are most energy efficient. I assume that SSDs are better than spinning disks, and passive cooling better than fans. Beyond that I have no idea--e.g., which types of display, memory, power supply, etc. are best.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a budget or a preferred screen size, or is the only thing that matters is the wattage? Would you mind a laptop that had a slightly higher wattage, but had better life?

Comment: Why can't it be a tablet with a keyboard?

Comment: How about a Chromebook? The ARM SoCs are very low power. Or is your real requirement "has windows" instead of "not a tablet".

Comment: Will second others--what are you requirements for a "laptop"? Does it need to run Windows? If you're okay with something that runs ARM, you'll be able to get much lower power than anything that runs x86. (There's a reason Intel never broke into the mobile phone market...)

Answer (score 1):

The **Liberty Computer** is a small, credit card sized computer that is designed to use minimal power as well as offer the highest standard of privacy. In this reviewer video and [interview with the developer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GspUDdNlsng) the reviewer reports under **3 W** idle usage.

In this [**Crowd Supply**](https://www.crowdsupply.com/eoma68/micro-desktop) page the computer is called the EOMA68 Micro-Desktop computer. The cost is 65 dollars pre-order but is projected to drop to 30 dollars on the market.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this as well. So far I have found a few promising mini PCs that are somewhat popular, such as as the Gigabyte Brix.

Anandtech's review of a Bay Trail **Gigabyte Brix** shows a power consumption of [5.79 W at idle and 17.28 W under load.](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8641/gigabyte-brix-gbbxbt1900-review-a-bay-trail-ucff-pc/6) The **ECS Liva** looks even better, with a Techspot review claiming the ECS goes [from 4 watts at idle to 10 watts at full load](https://www.techspot.com/review/907-ecs-liva-mini-pc/page9.html)

I'm not sure if that will satisfy your needs, and there may be drawbacks if your display has a overly high resolution.